# Role of null in performance tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

This query is regarding performance tuning of a query.
I have a table TEST1, which has 200,000 rows.
the table structure is as below.

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(16)
BRANCH              VARCHAR2(10)
ACCT_NAME           VARCHAR2(100)
BALANCE             NUMBER(20,5)
BANK_ID             VARCHAR2(10)
SCHM_CODE           VARCHAR2(10)
CUST_ID             VARCHAR2(10)
```

And the indexes are as below.

```
fields              Index Name              Uniquness
ACCOUNT_NUMBER      IDX_TEST_ACCT           UNIQUE
SCHM_CODE,BRANCH    IDX_TEST_SCHM_BR        NONUNIQUE
```

Also I have one more table STATUS,

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(16)
STATUS              VARCHAR2(2)
ACCOUNT_NUMBER      IDX_STATUS_ACCT         UNIQUE
```

When I write a query joining to table tables like below, execution too much time and is costly query.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER,STATUS
FROM TEST,STATUS
where TEST.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = STATUS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
AND TEST.BRANCH = '1000';
```

There is query return by product team to fetch the same details has ||null 
in where condition, the query is returning the same results but the 
performance is very good compared to my query.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER,STATUS
FROM TEST,STATUS
where TEST.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = STATUS.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
AND TEST.BRANCH||NULL = '1000';
```

Can anyone explain me how `||null` in the where condition made that difference.

I am writing this because, I want to know how it made the difference and want to use wherever it is possible.

Comment: Learn to use modern, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I don't think NULL plays any role here in the performance difference. You need an index on BRANCH column in the TEST table

Comment: you can check the plan for your query to look for difference. Maybe "null" is forcing to use an index. Try EXPLAIN PLAN FOR <your query> in sqlplus or use explain plan window of pl/sql developer.

Comment: I suspect the null is *stopping* it using an index (skip-scan), changing the driving table in the process. Get the execution plans of both queries and compare. If the performance is that different on so few records you might want to check your statistics are up to date. There isn't a general 'add null' pattern you can use 'wherever it is possible' though.

Comment: I suspect that your query must not be giving an answer. Instead, it must be giving you the error --- **ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined** as `ACCOUNT_NUMBER` is present in `SELECT` clause without any alias and present in both the tables

Comment: Learn how to use the performance analysis tools in your DBMS. Even EXPLAIN will tell you  lot (once you fix the obvious error). The second query will ignore the index including 'BRANCH'. Depending on the data distribution and type of index, it *may* use a skip scan for the for the first query. Running a full table scan against TEST might be faster than the indexed lookup. Check your stats.

Comment: @symcbean is right -- if a query is returning about 20% or more of the rows in the table, an index is likely going to be slower than a full table scan.  In this case, where the join column is not in the first position in the index, a skip scan will take a lot more reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn on autotrace and get the execution plans of both queries, I would guess that your query is trying to use the index `IDX_TEST_SCHM_BR` and the other query cannot use the index due to the clause `TEST.BRANCH||NULL` and cannot use the index since that clause prevents the optimizer from using the index.

Normally, the use of a function on a table column prevents Oracle from using the index, and in your case appending a null to a table column with the `||` operator is like invoking the function `concat(TEST.BRANCH||NULL)`.  To make your query run faster, you can

1. Add a hint to ignore the index `SELECT /*+ NOINDEX(TEST1 IDX_TEST_SCHM_BR */ ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ...`  (Not recommended)
2. Create a new index with `BRANCH` as the only column (Recommended)

As @symcbean noted, if an index is not very selective, (IE: the query returns a lot of rows in the table), then a full table scan would probably be faster.  In this case, since the `BRANCH` column is not the first column in the index, Oracle has to skip through the index to find the rows that match the join criteria.  A *general* rule of thumb is if the query is returning more than *around* 20% of the rows, a full table scan is quicker.  In this case due to the index definition, Oracle has to read through several index entries, skipping along until it finds the next new `BRANCH` value, so in this case much less than 5% probably

Also ensure your tables have current statistics gathered, and if any of your columns are not null, you should specify that in the table definition to help Oracle optimizer avoid issues like you are having.

Comment: horse_w_null_name: notice I put *general* and *around* in my "rule of thumb" -- another rule of thumb: always test queries against _your_ data.